# Install MySQL connector/J in Docker container

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

I'm deploying an application to a pre-configured GlassFish Docker container on Elastic Beanstalk. I need to install the MySQL connector/J library so it's accessible to GlassFish. According to the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_dockerpreconfig.dockerfile.html), "With preconfigured Docker platforms you **cannot** use a configuration file to customize and configure the software that your application depends on." But it does state: "you can add a Dockerfile to your application's root folder."

They provide an example (with no explanation!) on installing a PostgreSQL library for Python but I'm using Java and MySQL. As I am completely unfamiliar with Docker (and really just need to configure this one thing), I can't figure out how to do it. Using [Amazon's example Dockerfile](https://github.com/aws/aws-eb-glassfish-dockerfiles/blob/master/4.1-jdk8/Dockerfile) I was able to come up with this:

```
FROM amazon/aws-eb-glassfish:4.1-jdk8-onbuild-3.5.1

# Exposes port 8080
EXPOSE 8080 3306

# Install MySQL dependencies
RUN curl -L -o /tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.34/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y /tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar libpq-dev && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

However, on application deploy, I'm getting the following error:

```
t update && apt-get install -y /tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar libpq-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*] returned a non-zero code: 100"
```

And obviously, my library is not installed. **How can I install the MySQL Connector/J library with a Dockerfile?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apt-get install -y /tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar
```

This is not how `apt-get` works. It installs debian packages.

There is a package called `libmysql-java` that may be what you want.

You might also try something like

```
RUN curl -L -o /mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.34/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar
ENV CLASSPATH=/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:${CLASSPATH}
```

Comment: Could you explain the last line: `ENV CLASSPATH=/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:${CLASSPATH}`? In particular the `${CLASSPATH}` part. I assume it's adding the jar to the class path. But does that refer to the class path or am I supposed to substitute a value in for it?

Comment: That's attempting to extend your existing `CLASSPATH` to include `mysql-connector-java.jar`. So if you had previously done `CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/java`, you'd now have `/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:/usr/lib/java`.

Comment: On my local environment (not Docker), I would places the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar` into the following folder in my GlassFish Server: `glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/`. Am I correct in assuming that to do this with GlassFish running in Docker I would place the jar into `/usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/`?

Comment: I don't know about `/usr/local` specifically, but yes, wherever you'd put the jar-file. If you do `docker run -it amazon/aws-eb-glassfish:4.1-jdk8-onbuild-3.5.1 bash`, you should be able to get an interactive shell on the container and use that to figure out where the jar needs to go.

Comment: Do you know of a way to see the docker folder structures with an ssh client (putty)? Whenever I run the bash command, as you specified in your last comment, I never get a response.

Comment: You can't use an SSH client unless you run an SSH server inside the container (not recommended). I see the problem: it's an onbuild container, so you can run the way I'm expecting. Instead: `docker run --rm --name=test amazon/aws-eb-glassfish:4.1-jdk8-onbuild-3.5.1` and then in another terminal `docker exec -it foo bash`. That second command will get you a shell inside the container as long as the first command is still running.